# Get Microsoft Teams meeting subject from ThreadId

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

We are using Microsoft Calls SDK. When a call related to a Microsoft Teams meeting is created, the call contains the threadId for the meeting. The threadId is of the form:
19:meeting_ZTE0YjlmYzgtMGM0Yi00YmI5LWI1OTMtMzMxOWE3ZmI5MDU1@thread.v2

Is there a way to get the meeting subject or any other information about the meeting from this?

Update 4/10/20: This is what I get if I try to get more information from the /app/calls/{callId}

```
    {
  "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#communications/calls/$entity",
  "id": "801f0400-731f-43dd-804f-788a98f4ad47",
  "state": "established",
  "transferState": null,
  "terminationReason": null,
  "direction": "outgoing",
  "ringingTimeoutInSeconds": null,
  "subject": null,
  "callbackUri": "https://xxxx/api/v1/xxxxx/calls",
  "requestedModalities": [
    "audio",
    "video"
  ],
  "activeModalities": [
    "Audio",
    "Video",
    "VideoBasedScreenSharing"
  ],
  "routingPolicies": [],
  "tenantId": "xxxxx",
  "myParticipantId": "dbf2fb49-2be6-42ee-9b43-b9502890160f",
  "callChainId": "e3a58e36-9563-454e-873f-525994d0420c",
  "replacesContext": "aHR0cHM6Ly9iLWNjLXVzZWEyLTAyLmNjLnNreXBlLmNvbS9jYy92MS9hY3RpdmUvN2ZmNWMzMWMtYTdhMS00NjdmLWI2YWMtN2Q1NTc2ZDZlZGU3LzE1NTY5NTg2Ni9hMy8xNTU2OTYwMTMvcmVwbGFjZW1lbnQ/aT0yJmU9NjM3MjE1NDI0MTU4MzE2ODIw",
  "mediaState": null,
  "resultInfo": null,
  "answeredBy": null,
  "callOptions": null,
  "meetingCapability": {
    "allowAnonymousUsersToDialOut": false,
    "autoAdmittedUsers": "EveryoneInCompany",
    "allowAnonymousUsersToStartMeeting": false,
    "entryExitNotificationsEnabled": true
  },
  "toneInfo": null,
  "incomingContext": null,
  "terminationSender": null,
  "callRoutes": [],
  "source": {
    "endpointType": null,
    "region": null,
    "languageId": null,
    "countryCode": null,
    "identity": {
      "user": null,
      "phone": null,
      "guest": null,
      "encrypted": null,
      "onPremises": null,
      "applicationInstance": null,
      "device": null,
      "application": {
        "id": "xxxxx",
        "displayName": null,
        "tenantId": null
      }
    }
  },
  "targets": [],
  "mediaConfig": {
    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.serviceHostedMediaConfig",
    "preFetchMedia": []
  },
  "chatInfo": {
    "threadId": "19:meeting_ZTE0YjlmYzgtMGM0Yi00YmI5LWI1OTMtMzMxOWE3ZmI5MDU0@thread.v2",
    "messageId": "0",
    "replyChainMessageId": null
  },
  "meetingInfo": {
    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.organizerMeetingInfo",
    "allowConversationWithoutHost": null,
    "lobbyBypass": null,
    "organizer": {
      "phone": null,
      "guest": null,
      "encrypted": null,
      "onPremises": null,
      "applicationInstance": null,
      "application": null,
      "device": null,
      "user": {
        "id": "xxxxx",
        "displayName": null,
        "tenantId": "xxxxxx"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you tried GET call method. You can get info like subject from it.

For example,

GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/communications/calls/2f1a1100-b174-40a0-aba7-0b405e01ed92

Comment: Hello, this doesn't work. The subject is null. I have updated my original question with the response I am getting.